# Find the indices of the nearest neighbor pairs of a peak

Tags: r, nearest-neighbor

I was wondering if there is a more straightford way of finding the positions of the nearest neighbors  within vector `v`, prior and after the peak `p`, which are close or equal to value `a`.

I have vector `v`, peak `p` and value `a`:

```
v <- c(4,7,1,4,12,10,9,6,2,8)
p <- 12
a <- 3
```

The nearest neighbors of `p` within `v`, which are close or equal to `a`, should be

```
nn <- c(4,2)
```

The positions of `nn` within `v` should be

```
nn_pos <- c(4,9)
```

Comment: I updated my questions. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Yes it sounds better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you want to use the peak, but I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
ppos <- which.min(abs(v - p))
dis <- abs(v - a)
output<- c(ppos - which.min(dis[(ppos-1):1]), ppos + which.min(dis[(ppos+1):length(v)]))
output
[1] 4 9
v[output]
[1] 4 2
```

Comment: I updated my question, as it wasn't exactly what I wanted.

Comment: The positions are just these: c(ppos - which.min(dis[(ppos-1):1]), ppos + which.min(dis[(ppos+1):length(v)]))

Comment: Got it. I just want to see how symmetric the crest of the signal is by looking at the distance between nearest neighbor and peak prior to the peak, and at the distance between peak and nearest neighbor after the peak.

Answer (score 2):

```
> tail(sort(v[v-a < 0]), 1)
[1] 2
> head(sort(v[v-a > 0]), 1)
[1] 4
```

Comment: I know I should have asked from the beginning, but I want the indices of the nearest neighbors. For example, if I have 4 instead of 2 as the first value in `v`, I would get 2 indices for the nearest neighbor prior to the peak.

Comment: So you want it to return elements 1 and 4?

Comment: I updated my question. I want it to return indices 4 and 9 of `v`.